# Tail Loss Probing Timer of TCP

Tags: tcp

I've been wrapping my head around how TLP timer works that helps in faster loss recovery especially when packets are lost at end of transmission thus saving RTO(Retransmit Time Out) time. In normal scenario `N TLP packets` are sent and `N TLP dupacks` are expected. Are these TLP packets sent at an increasing time intervals i.e., ***[1, 2, 4 .. , K]***? Are these TLP packets different or same as lost or new packet? Is fast retransmit decided at end of TLP episode?

Comment: That is an experimental implementation on Linux, not a standard.

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/542642/ Implementation from 2013  .. so assumed TLP is getting into TCP .. Is it because IETF hasn’t finalised draft ?

Comment: There was a [related RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8985) released last month, but it will take a while for that to be adopted. I know of no standard implementation. You would be better served to read the new standard.